# glob.glob returning Index out of range

Tags: python, glob

It says index out of range. It prints flower path correctly but when I try to print flower_path with index then it gives me the error.

```
flower_path = os.path.join(DATASET_PATH, flowers_cls[1], '*')
print(flower_path)

# glob through the directory (returns a list of all file paths)
flower_path = glob.glob(flower_path, recursive=True)
print(flower_path[3]) # access an individual file
```

Comment: Please show the output of `flower_path` and `glob.glob(...)`

Comment: It appears that `flower_ path` has at most 3 elements (numbered 0..2), and your code is expecting there to be 4.

Comment: output of flower_path is flowers\rose\*

Comment: And glob is returning the list in google collab but not in Jupyter. Is this the problem of os.path.join or something else I want to run the code on my pc

Comment: The function isn't returning an error, an exception is being raised when it is executing. When exceptions are raised, they display the error message and something called a backtrace. Please copy and paste the full backtrace into your question.